# TOAD Scheme browser error when executing a package

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, toad

I am getting an error

```
ORA-01086: Savepoint 'somesavepoint' never established
ORA-06512: at MyPackage, line 500
ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
ORA-06512: at MyPackage, line 650
ORA-06512: at line2
```

Only happening when I execute the package from the schema browser of TOAD.

Doesn't happen when I execute it from editor

```
EXEC MyPackage.Procedure
```

Is anyone aware of any problems related to this? How can this be solved?

Comment: Could it be the side effect of another error causing a commit/rollback). I assume the creation of the savepoint is in the package, so does a DBMS_OUTPUT or other debugging technique demonstrate it is being issued ?

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-01086` occurs when you commit and then ask to rollback to your savepoint. So when you use TOAD schema browser, there must have been an open bug at that moment to apply a commit or perform a DDL within the session. If you would have had two different TOAD sessions then this should not happen.

Try to have two different sessions

- One with Schema Browser
- Another with normal Editor

This should be resolving the issue. Else check for quest website for open bugs on your TOAD version.